# Javascript callback function inside ajax

Tags: javascript

how would i do this?

```
function DoStuffAndCallBack(callback){
      $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
      callback();

    });
}

DoStuffAndCallBack(DoneFunction);

function DoneFunction(){
  console.log('done stuff');
}
```

I am getting 'callback' as undefined.Is there a way to do this, i know there are promises and what not but how can i do this in this instance.

Comment: I don't see why that shouldn't work.

Comment: The code as quoted is fine, the problem is outside the quoted code.

Comment: A probable cause (guessing from number of mistakes in my team): Maybe you defined the callback function as `DoneFunction = function()` instead of `function DoneFunction()` ?

Comment: Can you give the full error printed in console @ionescu victor

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the "callback" is loosing its context inside your inner function i.e. inside the ajax call.

Try this -

```
function DoStuffAndCallBack(callback){
    this.callback = callback;
    var self = this;
    $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
      self.callback();
    });
}

DoStuffAndCallBack(DoneFunction);

function DoneFunction(){
  console.log('done stuff');
}
```

Comment: Why would it loose its context?

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) Here it is very well explained. In case of call backs we need to explicitly set the 'this'